# `undefined reference` when trying to interface C to call C++

Tags: c++, c, interface

I was trying to call C++ from C. I am not sure about the linking order. It could have been that to cause the error. For some reasons, the compiler complains `undefined reference to helloWorld`.

Could anyone advise?

main.c:

```
 #include "example.h"
 #include <stdio.h>
 int main(){
     helloWorld();
     return 0;
 }
```

example.h:

```
 #ifndef HEADER_FILE
 #define HEADER_FILE
 #ifdef __cplusplus
     extern "C" {
 #endif
         void helloWorld();
 #ifdef __cplusplus
     }
 #endif
 #endif
```

example.cpp:

```
 #include "example.h"
 #include <iostream>
 void helloWorld(){
     std::cout << "Hello World from CPP";
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: That should work and I can only assume you aren't linking-in `example.cpp` (`example.o`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this. While both work, one is "cleaner" than the other.  *Side note:* As trojanfoe pointed out, you may have left off the `.o` on the compile/link command.

Here's a two step process:

```
cc -c main.c
c++ -o mypgm example.cpp main.o
```

This is a bit ugly because the usual convention is that the source that gets compiled is the one with `main`

Here's the more usual way:

```
c++ -c example.cpp
cc -c main.c
c++ -o mypgm main.o example.o
```

NOTE: In both cases, the "linker" must be `c++` to resolve the `std::*` that `example.cpp` uses

---

**UPDATE:**

> What is `mypgm`?

`mypgm` [just an example name] is the name of the [fully linked and ready to run] *output* executable or program. It's the argument for the `-o` option. The linker takes your relocatable input `.o` files, links them together to produce the output file [that can now be run as a command].

It's pretty standard nomenclature for something that is arbitrary in example instruction or code sequences [like here on SO]. You could replace "mypgm" with "ursa_majors_test_program" or "example", or whatever you'd like. To run the program, then type `./mypgm` [or `./ursa_majors_test_program` or `./example`]

There's no *magic* to the name, just like there was no magic to you naming your source files `main.c` and `example.cpp`

It should be descriptive of function. If you had said you were working on a text editing program, in my example, I might have used `-o editor`

Comment: Got it. Thank you.
`c++ -c example.cpp`
`cc -c main.c`
`c++ -o out example.o main.o`
`./out`